# How to subset output of pandas contain statement to give all True values?

Tags: python, pandas

How to subset output of pandas contain statement to give all True values?

**Code**

```
df_2clean["p2_conf"].astype(str).str.contains(r'[^0-9+-:.\s]')
```

**Output**

```
0   False
1   False
2   False
3   False
4   True
```

Comment: does this work: `df_2clean=df_2clean[df_2clean["p2_conf"].astype(str).str.contains(r'[^0-9+-:.\s]')==True]`?

Comment: `df_2clean.iloc[df_2clean["p2_conf"].astype(str).str.contains(r'[^0-9+-:.\s]')==True]` it may work

Comment: @ ashraful16, NotImplementedError: iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available.

Comment: @YevKad, Many thanks, the code subsets based on the contain statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_2subset=df_2clean[df_2clean["p2_conf"].astype(str).str.contains(r'[^0-9+-:.\s]')==True]
```

Comment: You don't need the `== True` part.

Comment: @erip You are correct, thanks. I kept the code redundant for better demonstration and in case another subset based on `False` values will also be needed, so it will be more obvious how to get one.